# Pipe / direct image / video output to foreign server

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am working on a Project that involves taking the output from a Webcam which is in either jpg or h.264 format, and outputting it to a foreign server (HTTP / FTP would work, I am open minded). What is the most logical way of doing this.

I would imagine that it would be achieved with `(command) | (commandtooutput [params]) [location]`. Am I looking at this wrong?

With images, I would prefer to upload them periodically such as once a minute. Eventually I would like to allow for this period to be changed. Does this seem logical / realistic? I presume the most logical way to implement this would be with Python or BASH scripting, having the script read period information before each sync and then have the script adjust accordingly.

To give some background the output is from a Raspberry Pi's  `raspistill` or `raspivid`  program, (it will either be running ArchARM or the usual Raspbian). I decided not to place this question in those forums because I think it applies more any distro of Linux. I believe the only thing that is unique to the Pi in this situation is irrelevant to my question, however if this is an inappropriate place to ask let me know and I will be sure to move / delete the post.

Comment: You could looks at how `motion` works, it can do remote copy of the captures.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, so it might be closed. Also some solution/implementations do depend on whether you want to keep the files on the originating system or delete them after successful upload

Comment: @Anthon I apologize, I simply looking for a way of taking the output from a program which is an image or video and sending it to a remote server. I assume that the best way would be to pipe it [|] to a command that can send files to a a server (ftp) for example. I am not sure what the program is, and I was open to other suggestions.  
Emmanuel This is a good solution, however I do need to demonstrate uniqueness in my application, so I would prefer to demonstrate things I have create.

Comment: Not necessarily. I would probably write the images to some directory, and have a job scanning that directory for files to upload (and delete them/mark them as processed). That is more robust if the connection is down for a short time.

Comment: @Anthon Okay. So that's covered I still however need a realistic way to upload it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would decouple the generation of the images and the uploading. You can do this by writing the images to a directory and on a regular basis (daemon, cron job) upload the images. That way you are more robust in case the connection to the server is down for a short period (or the server is rebooting for some reason).

The uploading can be done using `rsync` or `rdiff-backup`, if you want to keep the originals on the source side. Both work well over `ssh`, for which you would need a private/public key (without password) and copy the public key to the server.

If you don't want to keep anything on the client, you probably can just have small script that upload the files using `scp` (again with using `ssh` underneath) and removing the files once copied.

Uploading using HTTP and automating FTP is in my experience somewhat more cumbersome, especially if you already have `ssh` running on the server. For calling `scp` or `rsync` or uploading using HTTP you con't need Python. If you have to use FTP you might want to use it's [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)

Comment: Thank you, when you refer to SSH are you implying that a remote client would be used to activate a script? I would like to make it a daemon based utility, does that still require SSH ?

Comment: SSH is the transfer protocol that `scp` uses (and so does rsync over ssh). No remote client activation, either use cron, or have the script be daemon and check every X seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the application [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome). It Here are 2 videos on youtube that show it being set up and configured.

- [How to set up "Motion" video surveillance on a Linux system - Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwDLkMPLTw0)
- [How to set up "Motion" video surveillance on a Linux system - Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAoA_J5HD0M)

Motion has facilities for relaying images to a remote server. You can use `wput` to relay images to a FTP server, for example.

```
on_picture_save wput −−binary −−remove−source−files \
  ftp://USERNAMEHERE@jonathangraft.com:PASSWORDHERE@MY.SERVERS.EXTERNAL.IP %f
```

Or you can use `scp`:

```
on_picture_save scp -P2222 %f user@server.com:/path/to/motion/files/backup/
```

Comment: This program will be very helpful, thank you .

Comment: @user2962219 - I've used it for years. It's extremely powerful. I esp. like the feature of automatically making timelapsed videos from a days worth of images. I then use the `on_video_save` to push these using an `scp` command to my NAS.